# iOS 17 RPSystemBroadcastPickerView not working

Tags: objective-c, ios17, rpsystembroadcastpickerview

My existing code is working properly in iOS < 17 devices it records the iPhone screen and records audio as well simultaneously, but in iOS 17 devices the screen recording video is captured for only 2 seconds and then stops automatically, As its an extension, i don't have logs to debug the issue.

I have tested the same code in other iPhones and OS less than 17, its working fine but in iOS 17 devices this issue is coming.

```
@try {
        NSLog(@“initAssesWriter”);
        
        
        NSError *error = nil;
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        _videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                        _filePath fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
            error:&error];
        NSParameterAssert(_videoWriter);

        //Configure video
        NSDictionary* videoCompressionProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               [NSNumber numberWithDouble:2048*1024.0], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                                               nil ];
        
        NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       AVVideoCodecTypeH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:screenRect.size.width * 4], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:screenRect.size.height * 4], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                       videoCompressionProps, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                                       nil];
        
        _writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] ;
        _writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
        
        NSParameterAssert(_writerInput);
        NSParameterAssert([_videoWriter canAddInput:_writerInput]);
        [_videoWriter addInput:_writerInput];
        

        AudioChannelLayout acl;
        bzero( &acl, sizeof(acl));
        acl.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Mono;

        
        NSDictionary*  audioOutputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                        [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 1 ], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                        [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0 ], AVSampleRateKey,
                                        [ NSData dataWithBytes: &acl length: sizeof( AudioChannelLayout ) ], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                        [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 64000 ], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                              nil];
        
     
         _audioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                               assetWriterInputWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio
                               outputSettings: audioOutputSettings ];
         _audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES; // seems to work slightly better

        NSParameterAssert(_audioWriterInput);
        NSParameterAssert([_videoWriter canAddInput:_audioWriterInput]);
        [_videoWriter addInput:_audioWriterInput];
        [_videoWriter setMovieFragmentInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 600)];
        
        [_videoWriter startWriting];

    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
    } @finally {
        
    }
```

```
-(void)processSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer withType:(RPSampleBufferType)sampleBufferType{
    @try {
        if(!_isRecordingStarted){
            [_videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)];
            _isRecordingStarted = YES;
            [self saveFlurryLogs:@"Assest writer Start Recording" Details:@""];
            NSLog(@"CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp");
        }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        [self saveFlurryLogs:@"Recording Start Execption" Details:exception.description];
    } @finally {
        
    }
    
    @try {
        switch (sampleBufferType) {
            case RPSampleBufferTypeVideo:
                // Handle video sample buffer
                if([_writerInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]){
                    [_writerInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                    NSLog(@"writing matadata Video");
                }
                break;
            case RPSampleBufferTypeAudioApp:
                // Handle audio sample buffer for app audio
                break;
            case RPSampleBufferTypeAudioMic:
                if([_audioWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]){
                    [_audioWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                    NSLog(@"writing matadata Audio");
                }
                // Handle audio sample buffer for mic audio
                break;
                
            default:
                break;
        }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        [self saveFlurryLogs:@"Packet Write Execption" Details:exception.description];
    } @finally {
        
    }
}
```